# What's the best way to parse JSON in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following json content that I'm pulling from a different location:

#### JSON

```
[
   {
      "global_event":{
         "ending_at":"2011-11-07T02:00:00Z",
         "short_url":"http://bit.ly/reAhRw",
         "created_at":"2011-10-04T14:25:41Z",
         "event_responses":[

         ],
         "addresses":{
            "location":{
               "city":"blah",
               "latitude":30.205288,
               "zipcode":"343434",
               "street":"blah",
               "longitude":-95.475289,
               "state":"TX"
            }
         },
         "body":"blahblahblah",
         "euid":"2f489d0c82d167f1c16aba5d3b4c29ade6f1d52a",
         "title":"Fusion",
         "updated_at":"2011-10-04T14:26:57Z",
         "event_roles":[

         ],
         "user":{
            "long_name":"Fusion Single",
            "nickname":""
         },
         "event_items":[

         ],
         "starting_at":"2011-11-07T00:00:00Z"
      }
   }
]
```

#### Controller

```
def events
    @json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(open('jsonfeed').read)
end
```

#### View

```
<ul>
<% @json.each do |event, data| %>
    <% event.each do |e, d| %>
        <li><%= e[:short_url] #doesn't work '%></li>
        <li><%= e['short_url'] #doesn't work '%></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to properly access the data within this json?  Is there a better way to do it than the approach I'm taking?

Comment: I'm no RoR slinger, but if your goal is to get `short_url` for each object in the array, your inner loop is not needed. Delete the `event.each` loop structure and just use `<li><%= event.global_event.short_url %></li>`. My lack of RoR may have the syntax wrong, but the idea is `event` contains the array entry, which has a property `global_event`, which has a property `short_url`. Yes?

Comment: EDIT: Second look. You may need `<%= data.global_event.short_url %>` since `event` is likely assigned the index of the array (0).

Comment: Hmm, no that doesn't seem to be doing it.

Comment: What results are you getting? I've just about exhausted my ignorance.

Comment: I'm getting an 'undefined method global events,' because I'm also unsure of the syntax 0.o I've also tried ['global_events'] etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug, just do something like this.

Your first loop is for an array, so only needs a single variable in the block:

```
<ul>
  <% @json.each do |event| %>
    <% event.each do |e, d| %>
      <li><%=h e.inspect %> / <%=h d.inspect %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It's hard to write something that will work exactly as we can only see the first event.  But I'd be looking at the [ / { characters to see whether you're expecting a hash or an array.

Comment: Awesome!  The items I was looking for were in 'd,' so it worked by doing d['short_url']