# How to parse the json data or (json code) from Ruby on rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

I have an Ruby on rails source,code now i want to parse the data, and send the data.In my code,it will fetches the name from user and display it,How to parse the data in ROR.

This is my controller.rb code

```
def index
    @hotels = Hotel.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotels }
    end
  end

  # GET /hotels/1
  # GET /hotels/1.json
  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotel }
    end
  end

  # GET /hotels/new
  # GET /hotels/new.json
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @hotel }
    end
  end

  # GET /hotels/1/edit
  def edit
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /hotels
  # POST /hotels.json
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @hotel, status: :created, location: @hotel }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @hotel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /hotels/1
  # PUT /hotels/1.json
  def update
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.update_attributes(params[:hotel])
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Hotel was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @hotel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /hotels/1
  # DELETE /hotels/1.json
  def destroy
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
    @hotel.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to hotels_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

How to parse these data in ROR using Json
**HOw to write parsing json file for these data,how to do that one**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways:

1. Create method `to_json` for each model
2. Create view named, i.e. `hotels/index.json.erb` and write JSON code using ERb templating engine

   ```
   [
     <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
       { 'id': <%= hotel.id %>, 'name': "<%= hotel.name %>" },
     <% end %>
   ]
   ```
3. Use library like [`jbuilder`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) (on the bottom of page is list of alternatives to JBuilder)

   ```
   # hotels/index.json.jbuilder
   json.array!(@hotels) do |hotel|
     json.id hotel.id
     json.name hotel.name
   end
   ```

Comment: could you provide answer for my solution,i am new to one,

Comment: How to write json file for the above controller,could you give the solution

Comment: Dude this answer is enough or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735851/how-to-use-post-method-in-ror-using-json

Answer (score 2):

```
    **Answer of my question**
```

This part we have to do in controller
hotelscontroller.erb

```
  respond_to :json, :xml
      def index
        @hotels = Hotel.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @hotels.to_json(:only => [ :id, :name ]) }
        end
      end
```

view/index.json.erb

```
[
  <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    { 'id': <%= hotel.id %>, 'name': "<%= hotel.name %>" },
  <% end %>
]
```

routes.rb

```
get 'hotels' => 'hotels#index', :as => 'hotels'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can covert a hash to json by `to_json` method. For reference please see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

for example, if you want to write all hotels to external file.

```
file = File.open("hotels.txt", "w")
file.puts Hotel.all.to_json
file.close
```

this will write all hotels in external file `hotels.txt`

Comment: Dude could you give your answer,how to write the json file for my controller.I am new to json,give me answer for my question

Comment: I want to get the data from the user,that what in my code,its a scaffolding.how to parse the data,which user providing

Comment: could you provide solution for me @Ramiz Raja

Comment: Do you want to write json version of user object to an external file?

Comment: Do you want to write json version of user object to an external file?

Comment: yes,i want how to write json file for the above code,thats what i need dude

Comment: This is for server side. File will be saved on server machine, not client.

Comment: ya actually i also dont need client one,i will show u one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143174/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-json-in-ruby-on-rails , if u see link,there will controller and json also like that we need