# Using fetch API to get data from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am building a react on rails project to learn some new things.  I am trying to use the fetch API to get data from the db.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461450/how-to-parsing-the-json-data-or-json-code-from-ruby-on-rails) method and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824551/rendering-json-in-controller) one.  But I might be implementing them wrong.

This is my fetch route:

```
fetch('/get_data')
      .then(response => {
        response.json();
      })
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I have my route set up in Ruby on Rails:

```
match '/get_data' => 'get_data#pull', via: :get
```

I have my controller just doing something simple at the moment to see if I can get any data.

```
class GetDataController < ApplicationController
  def pull
    @allproduct = Product.all
    render json: @allproduct
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help in pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: First thing I note here is that you are missing pull action at line fetch('/get_data/pull')

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary with the given route.

Comment: What actually happens in your browser when you run this code? Anything in the console or network tab that might give you a clue?

Comment: @PeterMellett I am getting undefined in the console.  And the network tab I am seeing a few GET request.  One for the HTML  and the one I have defined get_data which is returninf a 304 status code.

Comment: Oh! Return the result of `response.json()` from your first `then`, you're console logging nothing because there is nothing returned for the next call in the promise chain

Comment: OH MAN!  @PeterMellett. Thank you.  What a bone head move.

Comment: No problem! Please add an answer with your solution and accept it :-)

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that I needed a return statement in my fetch call. :)

```
fetch('/get_data')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => console.log(data));
```